# How to put the fixed position element below every other element with a higher z-index?

Tags: html, css

Considering the following code, you can see an HTML element, with elements nested in each other, starting from `.depth-0`, and going all the way down to `.depth-4`.

At the last depth, there is a special class element, `.fixed-slide-down`. What I intend to do, is the following: when someone clicks on an element at `.depth-4`, if that element has a sibling with `.fixed-slide-down`, the slide-down should do what it's name suggest, and, well, slide-down:) To achieve this, the slide-down should appear from behind the menu-bar (which in this example, is named `.depth-0`). I managed to put the `position: fixed` slide-down element, BEHIND his direct parent `.depth-3`, but I can't put it behind every other parent (or behind every other depth).

```css
.depth-0 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.depth1 {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.depth-1.left {
  width: 30px;
}

.depth-1.right {
  width: calc(100% - 35px);
}

.depth-2 {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.depth-3 {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.depth-4 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.fixed-slide-down {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='depth-0'>
  <div class='depth-1 left'>
    Left
  </div>
  <div class='depth-1 right'>
    <div class='depth-2'>
      <div class='depth-3'>
        <div class='depth-4'>
          Button 1
        </div>
        <div class='fixed-slide-down'>
          Slidedown
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='depth-3'>
        <div class='depth-4'>
          Button 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without changing the current HTML structure, is it possible to achieve the desired behaviour? (To put the slide-down, with z-index, BEHIND every element which has a `.depth-x` class?)

If not, what HTML structural changes would be necessary?

I have to keep the slide-down at `position:fixed`, because it should have a width of 100% of the screen width, and it should be positioned at exactly the left edge of the screen (so basically it should cover the whole screen horizontally). With `position: absolute`, I've managed to get the desired result, I've even managed to make the slide-down container full screen wide, but I can't position it to the left edge of the screen that way.

An additional helpful solution for my problem would be, a method, to make an absolutely positioned element, stick to the LEFT edge of the screen, when his parent is not positioned directly there. If I am not mistaken, this is impossible at the moment with only `HTML` and `CSS`, but perhaps I am mistaken.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eyfyfLrq/

Comment: The problem you have is that you have to increase the z-index of the fixed element

Comment: To what extent? If I increase the z-index of the fixed element, it still won't go behind all of it's indirect parents.

Comment: Try using !important after the z-index

Comment: If you can afford getting rid of `position: relative` from each of your slide-down container's parents, you'll be able position it absolutely in terms of the full screen. Elements positioned absolutely will take their nearest relatively positioned parent as their point of reference. If there is no relatively positioned parent, body will be used as the reference.

Comment: @Elise unfortunatly I can't afford to do that, as it destroys other z-index related design elements in my page... arghh, I hate z-index, z-index hell:|

Comment: Okay.. I'm confused about what you're trying to do with the z-indexes though – you've got `z-index: 1` on your slide-down element, whereas if you need it to go behind other elements, would you not use a negative z-index? If I use `z-index: -1` in your fiddle and remove all other z-indexes, it goes behind everything else.

Comment: @Elise yeah, but with z-index: -1, the element becomes unclickable in Firefox. :( I've completetly redone the HTML structure of this navbar, and managed to solve it that way, but a solution without redoing the whole HTML would be still helpful.